# Using Reflection To Find ArrayList Object Properties

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

What I have is an ArrayList of objects and I am trying to use reflection to get the name of each property of each object in the ArrayList. For example:

```
private class TestClass
{
    private int m_IntProp;

    private string m_StrProp;
    public string StrProp
    {
        get
        {
            return m_StrProp;
        }

        set
        {
            m_StrProp = value;
        }
    }

    public int IntProp
    {
        get
        {
            return m_IntProp;
        }

        set
        {
            m_IntProp = value;
        }
    }
}

ArrayList al = new ArrayList();
TestClass tc1 = new TestClass();
TestClass tc2 = new TestClass();
tc1.IntProp = 5;
tc1.StrProp = "Test 1";
tc2.IntProp = 10;
tc2.StrPRop = "Test 2";
al.Add(tc1);
al.Add(tc2);

foreach (object obj in al)
{
    // Here is where I need help
    // I need to be able to read the properties
    // StrProp and IntProp. Keep in mind that
    // this ArrayList may not always contain
    // TestClass objects. It can be any object,
    // which is why I think I need to use reflection.
}
```

Comment: Any reason you're using an ArrayList and not a [List<TestClass>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx)?

Comment: @dtb - Yes, because my list may not necessarily be a TestClass. It can hold any object.

Comment: `List<object>` would be more appropriate.

Comment: Maybe you could also consider using an interface. But this of course would depend on the situation that you are actually using this for.

Comment: @spender - Isn't List<object> basically the same as an ArrayList? Other then maybe for clarity's sake?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
foreach (object obj in al)
{
    foreach(PropertyInfo prop in obj.GetType().GetProperties(
         BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance))
    {
        object value = prop.GetValue(obj, null);
        string name = prop.Name;
        // ^^^^ use those
    }
}
```

Comment: This might look to be the best answer. I will try it now. Thanks

Comment: This works perfect. Only other thing though, Marc, is there a way to know if the property is a string, int, float, decimal, or other (none of the above)?

Comment: @icemanind well, you could check `prop.PropertyType`, or more conveniently a `switch(Type.GetTypeCode(prop.PropertyType))` which is an enum with most of the common basic types.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `as` operator so that you don't have to use Reflection.

```
foreach(object obj in al)
{
     var testClass = obj as TestClass;
     if (testClass != null)
     {
        //Do stuff
     }
}
```

Comment: "Keep in mind that this ArrayList may not always contain TestClass objects. It can be any object," (from the question)

Comment: You got "as TestClass", but the List may not have TestClass objects. It may hold a different type of object all together

Comment: Casting an object other than a TestClass object would then return null would it not?

Comment: This might actually be either a great solution or not, depending on the exact intent of the questioner.

Comment: @Adam - but how would getting a null help achieve the aim of "to get the name of each property of each object in the ArrayList."

Answer (score 0):

It's as simple as this:

```
PropertyInfo[] props = obj.GetType().GetProperties();
```

The GetType method will return the actual type, not `object`. Each of the `PropertyInfo` objects will have a Name property.